# Regular expression to extract target url from a htaccess rewrite rule string in php?

Tags: php, regex

I need to check our htaccess rewrite rules if the target url is still ok. For this task I want to be able extract the target part from any rewrite rule. Actually what I need is an appropriate regular expression pattern.

Typical htaccess rewrite rules may look like this:

RewriteRule ^media/content/some_source.pdf$ **/** [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^another_source/with_subfolder([-0-9a-zA-Z\w]*) **landingpages/some_folder/target.php** [L]

The **fat** part needs to be extracted! Hope somebody is more familiar with regex to help me solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explode on ' ' space and then the 3rd item (index 2) will do the job just fine

Comment: In the exact same second I thought about explode. Thank you anyway!